# Find and rename files by pattern works in Debian, but not in CentOS7

Tags: bash, find, rename

I need to find and rename files with question mark in names. 
Example: "style.css?ver=111" should become "style.css"

I use this command

```
find . -type f -name "*\?*" -exec rename 's/\?.*//' '{}' \;
```

In Debian all works fine, but in CentOS7 I get and error that "rename: not enough arguments
"

Any ideas why?

Comment: Differently from `find`, `rename` is not a standard tool. Go for `mv` for portability. But, addressing your question, the first step is to find out the version of the `rename` on each machine.

Comment: It looks like `rename` on CentOS is the version from the util-linux package (which is named [rename.ul](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/util-linux/rename.ul.1.en.html) on Debian) and not the Perl `rename` script.

Comment: @Freddy absolutely right - how I can install it ?

Comment: @Quasímodo - Can you please assist with `mv` syntax - I'm trying but without luck

Comment: The problem is that you need to provide each found filename twice, so it will be more complicated. See answer.

Comment: It seems to be in the [prename](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/prename-1.9-5.el7.noarch.rpm.html) package (with name `prename`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a reliable option that should work in any POSIX-compliant system, you may use

```
find . -type f -name "*\?*" -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1%%\?*}"' findshell {} \;
```

`$1` is the name of each file found and `${1%%\?*}` is a construct that strips the substring starting from the question mark.

That should be enough if you have a few matching files. If you need it, a more efficient alternative is

```
find . -type f -name "*\?*" -exec sh -c '
    for file in "$@"; do
        mv -- "$file" "${file%%\?*}"
    done
' findshell {} +
```

Comment: Works like a charm, just explain what it is a `findshell` :)

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov `findshell` is just an arbitrary name given to this little miniature shell script it's running on the files. It doesn't matter much, it's really more of a placeholder than anything else. In this case, I assume the name is chosen because it's the shell running under `find`.

Comment: Yes, a placeholder useful for error-reporting when find is a part of a larger script (so you know from where the error comes). You will commonly find it as `find-sh`, and it is assigned to `$0` by `sh`.